# Using AG Grid api event listener to determine if a single row has been selected/deselected last

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

How I'm handling row mass actions in Ag Grid:

```
const handleSelectionChanged = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
  const { value } = event.target || { value: '' };
 
  if (value === 'selectAll') {
    api.forEachNode((node) => node.setSelected(true));
    //...
  }

  if (value === 'deselectAll') {
    api.forEachNode((node) => node.setSelected(false));
  }
}

api.addEventListener('selectionChanged', handleSelectionChanged);

return (
  <MenuItem
    value="selectAll"
  >
    Select All
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem
    value="deselectAll"
  >
    Deselect All
  </MenuItem> 
)
```

But using the event listener `api.addEventListener('selectionChanged', handleSelectionChanged)`, how can I distinguish a selection/deselection of a single row/node? `api.getSelectedRows()` gives me all currently selected. When select/deselect a single row, without using the button, the `event` object doesn't carry information I could use to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most frustrating thing about Ag-grid. `rowSelected` event is fired, either row is selected or deselected.
**You can't distinguish from the event.** You have to get a single node and call `node.isSelected()`

It seems you want to select or deselect all rows. I would do like this

```js
  <MenuItem
    onClick={() => gridApi.selectAll()}
  >
    Select All
  </MenuItem>

  <MenuItem
    onClick={() => gridApi.deselectAll()}
  >
     Deselect All
  </MenuItem>
```

You can check the detail here
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-selection-selectAll